# Ruby on Rails date overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a big problem with date overlapping in my application. I have a model Car `which: has_many :reservations`
and model Reservation which:

```
belongs_to :car
```

I'm building search form that will help find cars that not have reservations in the specified date range. My search form looks like this:

```
= horizontal_simple_form_for :cars, {url: cars_path, method: :get} do |f|
  = f.input :handover_date, as: :string, label: false
  = f.input :return_date, as: :string, label: false
  = f.submit class: 'btn btn-success'
```

And in my controller I filter cars based on params:

```
@cars = Car.joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", params[:cars][:handover_date], params[:cars][:return_date])
```

This code is based on ([Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap))
but this code not works properly.
In my db I have one car and one reservation for this car. This reservation is from 14 May to 20 May.
Now when I searching and I set in my form handover_date to 10 May and return_date to 16 May it shows me that Car is ready to create reservation but this is false because Car have already reservation from 14 May to 20 May...
I don't have any ideas how to resolve this thing.
Thank's everyone in advance.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619130/time-availability-comparison-using-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very close to the solution. I must use this:

```
@cars = Car.joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", params[:cars][:return_date], params[:cars][:handover_date])
```

instead of this:

```
@cars = Car.joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", params[:cars][:handover_date], params[:cars][:return_date])
```

Thank's everyone for help.